# Who is older? Batman or Superman?

Tags: dc, batman, superman

Assuming we count Superman's age as the age of Clark Kent in Earth Years, how does his age compare to Bruce Wayne in-universe?

Any answers are preferred to be from the same continuity if possible; but absent that cross-continuity answers are OK if less desirable.

Comment: This is actually a lead-up to my main question, which i'll ask based on the answer to this one.

Comment: At which point? *Dark Knight Rises* (and the comic it was inspired by) have a much older Bruce than the "usual". And both Clark & Bruce have been around since the 1940s or so, and in the prime of adulthood most of that time.

Comment: DKR doesn't have Superman as far as I know.

Comment: No, that part of the comment was only about Batman.

Comment: In TDKR, Batman is in his 50s, in DKR he's in his late 30s. In BvS he's 45ish. For Superman, in TDKR look below in my Answer. In DKR he doesn't exist. BvS he's late 20s plus or minus several hundred or thousand years dependant on how you reckon time.

Comment: @Durakken - for clarity, Superman's age for this question is the legal age of Clark Kent as per Kent papers, not biological age of Kal-El counting from actual birth on Krypton (which would include travel time to Earth and thus make the comparison meaningless)

Answer (score 8):

The answer is a bit difficult to answer because Batman's Birthday changes between February, May, October, and November while Superman's Birthday changes between February, June, and July of different years which could make Superman extremely older.

However most canon places Batman's Birth in the early part of Year -21 (Mostly accepted as February 19) and Clark Kent's birth records in late Year -21 or early Year -20. Kal-El according to new52 canon was born July of Year -21. according to Superman #14

So the answer is a bit convoluted...

Kal-El's birthday can be put the furthest back in time, but is generally not, and isn't currently.
Bruce Wayne's Birthday is before Clark Kent's and Kal-El's in most canon.
Batman is also active before Superman makes his debut in most canon.

This makes Bruce/Batman older than Clark/Superman a garentee in most canon, but Kal-El possibly "technically" older in a small percent of them depending on how you reckon time. In MoS for example, Krypton wasn't destroyed 20-ish years ago. It was destroyed hundreds of years ago, but Kal-El arrived on Earth as a baby which means in those canons we have no idea how much time passed for baby Kal-El and it could be that from Bruce's and Kal-El's count of days alive they have been alive the same number of days in those instances.

Hope that explain it...

Also fyi, in new52, they're both 31 at present as of pre-Rebirth. post Rebirth... this gets into Spoiler territory... Batman has been de-aged and Superman of new52 has died, replaced with the Bronze Age Superman 10+ years down the road which makes Rebirth era Superman around 50ish and Rebirth era Batman physically around 31, mentally and experiencally possibly around 50 or 60 depending on if he gets his memory back.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have very specifically indicated that Superman's age is to be measured as Clark Kent, to avoid difficulties introduced by "how many years between destruction of Krypton and arrival on Earth" wrinkle :)

Comment: Then Clark is younger than Bruce. If I remember right from my reading and compiling timeline data this is clear because Clark arrives on Earth in fall/winter of the year Bruce is born and the Kents say he was born/adopted during this time. If you have timeline questions I made the most comprehensive new52 timeline I know of with all the ref to where the info comes from, but some of it you have to logic out. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13WtjkyOA9IfJMj6s9aNjk8yiyuLvhvpW6UiHSC7DGVY/edit?usp=sharing Hope this helps, even though it's lacking data from after 2013, cuz i stopped reading